# How to send and get an object as function parameter in js

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function insertObject(obj) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.arguments[0] + ' ' + obj.arguments[1];
    // So I want to write "John James "
}

</script>

</head>
<body >

<button onclick="insertObject({name: "John", surname: “James”})">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is just so many wrong things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take the time to write out your question next time.

Meanwhile, hopefully this will get you going

```js
function insertObject(obj) {
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = obj.name + ' ' + obj.surname;
}
```

```html
Test
<button onclick='insertObject({name: "John", surname: "James"})'>Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```